# XSLT Namespace troubles

Tags: xslt, namespaces, filemaker

In the next step of a project I am working on I am having a problem with namespace statements in an xslt file. I admit that the problem is likely identical to that found in this question: [Filemaker XSL Importing blank fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302581/filemaker-xsl-importing-blank-fields). However, I'm not able to understand the solution there and feel that perhaps the answer may be a bit more simplistic, i.e. I've mucked up the syntax somehow.

The xml I'm working with is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ledesxml xmlns="http://www.ledes.org/ledes20.xsd">
      <firm>
        <lf_vendor_id>test</lf_vendor_id>
      </firm>
    </ledesxml>
```

The xslt I'm currently using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.ledes.org/ledes2000.xsd"
    xmlns:t="http://www.ledes.org/ledes2000.xsd"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">

<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">

    <METADATA>
        <FIELD NAME="lf_vendor_id" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    </METADATA>

    <RESULTSET>
        <ROW>
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="/t:ledesxml/t:firm/t:lf_vendor_id"/></DATA></COL>
        </ROW>
    </RESULTSET>

</FMPXMLRESULT>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The import to Filemaker results in a new record without any data. The xml input here is an industry standard and doesn't change (at least for present purposes).

The use of name spaces here is a bit confusing and is based almost entirely on the namespaces used in the question linked above. Using a wild card in the "value-of select" statement does work, but as you might expect, grabs all the text in the xml sample and not just the data in which I am interested.

Since the import seems to work and the name space convention seems to have worked for another poster, I'm at a bit of a loss. Does anyone have some pointers as to where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML document has `xmlns="http://www.ledes.org/ledes20.xsd"` while the XSLT declares `xmlns:t="http://www.ledes.org/ledes2000.xsd"` with `ledes2000` instead of `ledes20`. You will need to use the same namespace URL in both documents.

Comment: Again, you have saved the day. Thank you once more.